# Error with IEEE Access template and glossaries package

Tags: errors, glossaries, ieeeaccess

I'm experiencing an obscure issue when using the IEEE Access template (you can download it from [here](https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/ACCESS_latex_template_3.2023.zip)) combined with glossaries package to make an acronym list.

Here is the error message:

```
You can't use `\gdef' after \the.
```

which points at a random location in the tex, or at \end{document}.

I'm using Overleaf, but I get the same on my local computer. It doesn't prevent the compilation of the pdf and it doesn't cause a visible error in the output file, but it does prevent the journal from publishing my paper, apparently :)

I managed to narrow it down to the MRE below, here are the only things I know:

- it disappears if I remove the \makeglossaries part,
- with a different document class it's not coming up,

so it arises from the interaction between glossaries and ieeeaccess document class.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Worst case scenario, I'll just get rid of the acronyms list, even if I don't like the idea.

Here is the MRE:

```
% IEEE Access
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{li}{LI}{Lorem ipsum}


\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\lipsum[1-1]

\gls{li}

\EOD

\end{document}
```